# Is it possible to upload files to FTP server in Azure pipeline via VPN?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-pipelines, azure-vpn

I have an Azure pipeline where I build my app and publish its files to my computer which is configured as FTP server.

```
...

- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'ftp://pathtomyftp'
    username: 'user'
    password: 'pass'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: '/PublishFiles/'
    clean: true
    preservePaths: true
    trustSSL: false
```

Instead of publishing to my FTP server I would like to publish these files to a remote FTP server accessible only via VPN (like OpenVPN or/and Global VPN client). Is this possible to accomplish?

*I would like that the build stays on Azure agent, not that I would need to run Agent on my machine

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to upload files to FTP server in Azure pipeline via VPN?

I am afraid it is impossible to upload files to FTP server in Azure pipeline with hosted agent via VPN.

Since you're using microsoft-hosted agent which is not in the same network as your VM where the FTP server exists, you should make sure your ftp server can be accessible from **external** network.

So, if you need use VPN to access your remote FTP server, you could not to upload files to FTP server in Azure pipeline with hosted agent.

To resolve this issue, you have two possible solutions:

1. Using agent on your FTP server machine.
2. Configure your ftp server to make it accessible from external network instead of VPN.